# How to share pdf file over whatsapp or mail from react web app on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

Can we share pdf files from a React Web App on button click through whatsapp and mails.

Comment: The solution is - Web Share Api (first we have to convert pdf to image as right now only image and text sharing is allowed)